# remove ul class for li elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

i have a ul element like this

```
<ul class = 'check'> 
<li> stackOverFlow1 </li>
<li> stackOverFlow2 </li>
<li> stackOverFlow3 </li>
<li> stackOverFlow4 </li>
<li> stackOverFlow4 </li>
<ul>
```

how can i convert this to

```
<ul class = 'check'> 
<li> stackOverFlow1 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li> stackOverFlow2 </li>
</ul>
<ul class = 'check'> 
<li> stackOverFlow3 </li>
<li> stackOverFlow4 </li>
<li> stackOverFlow4 </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get this in pure javascript... Please Help...Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is not clear, what you have tried?

Comment: @Zain tried removing the ul class for one li element alone in the unordred list

Comment: your class name should be in single or double quotes

Comment: @Zain Quotes are only mandatory if the attribute contains spaces or other special characters.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. You're not removing anything, you're adding additional `ul` elements.

Comment: What is the logic for where the new `ul` tags go?

Comment: @Zain yes yes missed the quotes in class name...  just wants to remove specific ul class attribute.

Comment: @Barmar new ul node must go to selected node where caret position is present

Comment: What does your example have to do with that requirement?

Comment: What caret position? You really need to explain what you're trying to do better. All the details should be in the question, not in comments. Right now the question makes no sense. You say you want to remove a class, but that's not what your example shows.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the original to your desired result, you need to create new `ul` elements and append them to the parent container. Then you can move the `li` elements from the original `ul` to the appropriate new `ul`s using `appendChild`.

```js
var check = document.querySelector("ul.check");
var li = check.querySelectorAll("li");
var parent = check.parentElement;

var newUl1 = document.createElement("ul");
newUl1.appendChild(li[1]);
parent.appendChild(newUl1);

var newUl2 = document.createElement("ul");
newUl2.classList.add("check");
for (let i = 2; i < li.length; i++) {
  newUl2.appendChild(li[i]);
}
parent.appendChild(newUl2);
```

```css
.check {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="check">
    <li> stackOverFlow1 </li>
    <li> stackOverFlow2 </li>
    <li> stackOverFlow3 </li>
    <li> stackOverFlow4 </li>
    <li> stackOverFlow4 </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if do you want to delete the specific ul class then you can try it

```
  var index_to_delete=2;
    
 document.querySelectorAll('.check')[index_to_delete].removeAttribute('class');
```

Comment: How does this achieve what he shows in the example?

Comment: I think he just wants to remove specific ul class attribute.

Comment: @Zain yes thats the requirement